# UINavigationController and adding a badge to rightBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

How can I add a numeric badge to the rightBarButtonItem of a UINavigationController? I saw the same in some shopping cart applications.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do this manually (ie, create a view that draws the badge and number in). There's no API to set a badge value on a UINavigationBar.

Comment: Any chance you want to update the answer with some Swift code?